# is there some code for a basic R parser?

Tags: r, parsing

I am looking for a Bison/Flex implementation for parsing R code, so that I can use it in a C++ program to implement a programming language that makes use of R expressions.

I couldn't find anything available on Google, other than this:

https://github.com/halpo/parser

and this does not seem to be quite an R parser. (For example, I couldn't find the BNF grammar for R expressions.)

Is the only way left actually to download R source code and play with it? R is quite a complex piece of software, and I am not sure it would be very easy to isolate the parser from the rest of the code.

Comment: Not an answer but did you try to use `RInside`?

Comment: i think the highlight package dug into this sort of thing - Edit: actually, using the `parser` package.

Comment: @baptiste thanks. I am looking for writing a domain specific language that uses syntax similar to R, so I want to base myself on some bison/flex code for R. the parser package can be run inside R. When I looked into it, I couldn't find any BNF specification for R or something that I could use to continue from there.

Comment: correction: the parser package does include a source code for a parser, but it is post bison/flex, so it cannot be changed very easily. the BNF specification and the code which was used to generate this parser is not in the package source code.

Comment: scratch that. it was in a directory I didn't expect it to be... exploring now.

Comment: There is http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/gram.y and gram.c

Comment: You could embed R inside your c++ program, so that you do not even need to parse code anymore. And if you still want to parse it, just call R parse() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a better look:
https://github.com/halpo/parser/blob/master/inst/grammar/gram.y