# Parsing script statements in Java with Regex

Tags: java, regex, rjava, jri

I have the following R script in a java String variable (including new line characters):

```
d = 1
for (i in 1:150 ) {
 d = d + i;
}
print(d)
```

What I'm looking for is to obtain the R functions, regardless of new lines.

Following the previous example, I would get an array of three strings:

first: `d = 1`

second: `for (i in 1:150 ) {
     d = d + i;
    }`

third: `print(d)`

is this possible with Regex?

Comment: no it is not possible. look at this https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/r/R.g4

Comment: To do this right you have to recognize all valid R statements/expressions, which means you'll need to write a full parser for R and build a parse tree. Parsers may _use_ regex within them, but you can't parse this using _only_ regex.

Comment: The answer to this has a link to an R language parser written in C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028678/is-there-some-code-for-a-basic-r-parser

Comment: There are many open source parser generators available.  The following link has a list of some: http://java-source.net/open-source/parser-generators